# JAXB - Generate schema. Complex Type custom attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I need to generate following schema from java class using JAXB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
    <xs:element name="test" type="test"/>
    <xs:complexType name="testName" xdb:SQLType="WEBY_TEST_NAME">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How to add `xdb:SQLType="WEBY_TEST_NAME"` into complexType element using jaxb annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

i done same try for generating the schema for different tags, but the names which include reserve words or else need to declare as

@XmlElement(name="class")

```
public String getClasss() {
    return classs;
}
```

in pojo, so at time of coding it uses name which we provide, and in java program it uses the declared variables.

may be your declaration become

@XmlElement(name="xdb:SQLType")

```
public String getxdbSQLType() {
    return xdbSQLType;
}
```